# How to prevent Figma Agent to be added to Login Items

Tags: macos, figma

Every time I launch the native Figma app on macOS (macOS 13 Ventura) I get this notification:

> Login Item Added: "FigmaAgent.app" will open automatically when you log in. You can manage this in Login Items Settings.

[image: Notification on macOS]

And following the instructions on the notification I can remove the Login Item as expected, but I will get the notification again next time I launch the app, and the Login Item will be added once more.

[image: Login Item Settings with FigmaAgent.app on the list]

I want to remove it and never to be added again.
How can I do that?

Pd: I reached out to Figma support a few times, and they mostly ignored my messages, and when I asked why was I being ignored they gave me a rather unhelpful answer:

> Hey there, sorry for the delay & confusion. We didn't reply, because the answer was in your original tweet. Sorry if it wasn't obvious, but in the screenshot, you manage it from Login Items Settings: Apple menu > System Settings, click General in the sidebar, then Login Items.

To be very clear, I don't want to know how to remove FigmaAgent from Login Items, I want to know how to prevent it for being added again.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From https://twitter.com/qdoug/status/1374785043504185351:

This seems to work for removing FigmaAgent:

- Force Quit it in Activity Monitor
- Remove it in System Preferences -> Users & Groups -> Login Items
- Delete `~/Library/Application Support/Figma/FigmaAgent.app`
- Delete `/Applications/Figma.app/Contents/Library/FigmaAgent.app`
- touch "~/Library/Application Support/Figma/FigmaAgent.app" to stop it being re-enabled by updates

Comment: any idea how they are programmatically adding it in Login Items?

Comment: @Er.Khatri I'm aware of two ways to do this. One is through the deprecated `LSShareFileListInsertItemURL` api that can be set up in the app delegate during launch. The new way available as of Ventura (I think) is a framework called [SMAppService](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/servicemanagement/smappservice). I'm not sure which approach Figma uses.

Comment: Nice! Hopefully this doesn't need to be done again after an update?

Comment: @derpedy-doo Deopending on how they deploy updates, I'm afraid it may return. Hopefully they will address the lack of an option to disable it. If they don't one solution would be to create a plain file with the same name where the application wants to create the app bundle (after deleting it): `touch "~/Library/Application Support/Figma/FigmaAgent.app"`. Not tested!

Comment: Looks like this must be done after every update.

Comment: The solution below this one works through updates, unlike this accepted answer.

Comment: @Katerberg that is true, but see my comment in reply to derpedy-doo above which also solves the update problem.

Comment: @zjames not quite. if you just create the dummy file Figma will override it later. It is also not a good idea to delete the file inside the Figma.app itself as that also gets replaced with updates.

Comment: @marcaux You can't overwrite a plain file with a directory so it persists, takes one less step and doesn't require you to be an admin user.

Comment: @zjames are you sure? in my tests when the file is not marked as undeletable it will get deleted and replaced by figma.

Answer (score 41):

###### removing FigmaAgent.app

- `rm -fr ~/Library/Application\ Support/Figma/FigmaAgent.app`

###### creating a dummy file

- `touch ~/Library/Application\ Support/Figma/FigmaAgent.app`

###### make the file undeletable

- `sudo chflags -R schg ~/Library/Application\ Support/Figma/FigmaAgent.app`

Now Figma will not be able to override that file when it wants to update it and you don't have to fiddle with the .app everytime Figma updates itself.

Also the login item does not get created for me again after removal at this point.

Comment: In addition to the accepted answer, this indeed prevented FigmaAgent to appear after every update. And updates seem to work fine for me.

Comment: Doing gods work over here. Thank you @marcaux...

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to avoid that, but it involves a few steps and is rather hacky:

**1. Move Figma to a disk image**

- You have to create an empty disk image (e.g. .sparseimage) with Disk Utility
- Move the Figma.app from applications into that disk image
- delete the old Figma.app in the applications folder

**2. Locate the Figma Agent**

- After opening the disk image, right click on Figma.app to “Show Package Contents”
- Look for the FigmaAgent.app in the Library folder

**3. Create an Alias**

- Right Click on the FigmaAgent.app to “Make Alias”

**4. Replace the Figma Agent on your System with the Alias**

- Navigate to ~/Library/Application Support/Figma, or right click on the Login Item “FigmaAgent” in your System Settings to “Show in Finder”
- Rename or delete the existing FigmaAgent.app in that folder
- Move the alias you created in step 3 to this folder, and rename it to FigmaAgent.app

**What this will do**

On startup, the login item will try to launch FigmaAgent.app. But as this item now points to a non-mounted disk image, it will not work anymore. So FigmaAgent will no longer launch on startup.

Figma cannot replace the alias, it will not be removed with an update.

**Downsides**

- FigmaAgent can no longer be updated
- You have to mount/open the sparseimage each time you want to launch Figma